# Video Poker with luck modifier

Tags: java, game, combinatorics, brute-force

While grinding for coins on the GTA San Andreas casino poker machines I started to
wonder how exactly one might implement a luck modifier to a [video poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_poker) game without
it being completely obvious to the player, like it is in GTA.

This project implements it by brute force. When dealing cards it calculates the
probability for each possible poker hand, picks one at random and deals it to the
player. When the player discards cards, the game repeats the probability calculation
for the hands the player can get when their hand is stocked up. The player luck component
is implemented by adjusting the poker hand probabilities before one is chosen at random.

The reason for going with this approach, even though I can just look up the probabilities
of each poker hand from Wikipedia, is that I want to be able to play with a non-standard
deck. In GTA there is a graphics bug where the card picture for Queen of Clubs is replaced
with that of Queen of Spades. It does not affect the game there, which is a disappointment,
as in my opinion a cheating casino would fit the GTA world very well. In my sample app it
does affect the game and thus thus getting a flush with spades is slightly more probable
than usually.

### Performance

Calculating the initial probabilities is too slow. On a fairly new gaming laptop it
takes several seconds, enough to be a bit annoying to the player. Calculating the
probabilities after the player has discarded cards is not a performance issue, as
the deck is smaller and for most of the times the size of the combinations to calculate
is also smaller.

I have thought of few ways to improve the initial deal. One is by calculating the
probabilities from a fresh deck once when the game starts and using those probabilities
to randomly pick the initial hand. The actual cards would then be chosen by going
through all card combinations until the first one that matches the chosen poker hand
is found. This would fix most of the cases but the worst case would still be the same.
Another is to use the emergency brake in the combinator to stop the process once enough
samples have been found or too much time has passed. Since the deck is shuffled before
dealing, I don't think this should affect the randomness over several rounds too much.

## Review Scope

The project has way too much code for a full review so I have only included classes that
are strictly relevant to dealing the cards. I am at my wit's end when it comes to more
mathematical approaches to dealing the cards so I would appreciate suggestions for that.
But of course I appreciate any input you may have. Do you understand what the code does?
Does the naming make sense? Do the component structure make sense? What good programming principles am I violating?

The whole codebase is available at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/antti.brax/videopoker).

## The Code

The possible card combinations are calculated with a generic utility that finds all N-length combinations from a given set:

```
package fi.iki.asb.wheel.algorithm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BooleanSupplier;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

/**
 * Utility to generate all possible combinations of given size from
 * a given set.
 *
 * <p>This class is <i>not thread safe</i>.</p>
 */
public class Combinator<T> {

    /**
     * The set containing all the possible elements.
     */
    private final List<T> set;

    /**
     * The size of the combinations to produce.
     */
    private final int combinationSize;

    /**
     * Internal list that holds the current combination. This is
     * defined as a class member to reduce the number of throwaway
     * object creations in the combinator loop.
     */
    private final List<T> combination;

    /**
     * Unmodifiable wrapper to <code>combination</code> so that it
     * can be exposed to the consumer.
     */
    private final List<T> unmodifiableCombination;

    /**
     * Create a combinator that finds combinations from
     * <code>set</code> that have <code>combinationSize</code>
     * elements.
     *
     * @param set The set from which combinations are created.
     * @param combinationSize The size of combinations to create.
     */
    public Combinator(final List<T> set, final int combinationSize) {
        this.set = new ArrayList<>(set);
        this.combinationSize = combinationSize;
        this.combination = new ArrayList<>(combinationSize);
        this.unmodifiableCombination = Collections
                .unmodifiableList(combination);
    }

    /**
     * Find all combinations.
     *
     * @param combinationConsumer
     *      The consumer that receives the combinations.
     */
    public void findCombinations(
            final Consumer<List<T>> combinationConsumer) {
        findCombinations(set, combinationConsumer, () -> false);
    }

    /**
     * Find all combinations.
     *
     * @param combinationConsumer
     *      The consumer that receives the combinations.
     * @param emergencyBrake
     *      Checked periodically. If the supplier returns
     *      <code>true</code> the algorithm is stopped as
     *      soon as possible.
     */
    public void findCombinations(
            final Consumer<List<T>> combinationConsumer,
            final BooleanSupplier emergencyBrake) {
        findCombinations(set, combinationConsumer, emergencyBrake);
    }

    /**
     * "Jump pad" to recursiveFindCombinations that clears the
     * combination list in case the execution is interrupted
     * by an exception. 
     */
    private void findCombinations(
            final List<T> subset,
            final Consumer<List<T>> combinationConsumer,
            final BooleanSupplier emergencyBrake) {
        try {
            recursiveFindCombinations(subset, combinationConsumer,
                    emergencyBrake);
        } finally {
            combination.clear();
        }
    }

    private void recursiveFindCombinations(
            final List<T> subset,
            final Consumer<List<T>> combinationConsumer,
            final BooleanSupplier emergencyBrake) {

        if (combination.size() == combinationSize) {
            combinationConsumer.accept(unmodifiableCombination);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < subset.size(); i++) {
            if (emergencyBrake.getAsBoolean()) {
                return;
            }

            combination.add(subset.get(i));
            recursiveFindCombinations(
                subset.subList(i + 1, subset.size()),
                combinationConsumer,
                emergencyBrake);
            combination.remove(combination.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Poker hand probabilities are calculated by counting the number of 5 card combinations
that match each known poker hand and storing the counts as weights in a weighted set.
The probability counter is the consumer to the `Combinator`. The weighted set is not
part of the review, but it's code is [here](https://gitlab.com/antti.brax/reinventing-the-wheel/-/blob/main/src/main/java/fi/iki/asb/wheel/adt/impl/WeightedSet.java) if you want to take a look.

```
package fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.luckbased;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.Card;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.PokerHand;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.handmatcher.HandMatcher;
import fi.iki.asb.wheel.adt.impl.WeightedSet;

/**
 * Consumer that receives each possible combination to replace the
 * player's discarded cards. Tests if the combination with the player's
 * held cards matches any poker hand and records the probability of
 * each hand into a weighted set.
 */
class PokerHandProbabilityCounter implements Consumer<List<Card>> {

    /**
     * Poker hand probabilities stored as a weighted set.
     */
    private final WeightedSet<PokerHand> probabilities = new WeightedSet<>();

    /**
     * A random sample of each discovered poker hand.
     */
    private final Map<PokerHand, List<Card>> samples = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * The hand matcher used in this game.
     */
    private final HandMatcher handMatcher;

    /**
     * Internal data structure that contains the player's hand.
     */
    private final List<Card> heldCards;

    /**
     * List to temporarily contain the held cards and the suggested
     * cards to check which 
     */
    private final List<Card> currentHand = new ArrayList<>(5);

    PokerHandProbabilityCounter(
            final HandMatcher handMatcher,
            final List<Card> heldCards) {
        this.handMatcher = handMatcher;
        this.heldCards = heldCards;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(List<Card> dealtCards) {
        currentHand.clear();
        currentHand.addAll(heldCards);
        currentHand.addAll(dealtCards);

        final PokerHand hand = handMatcher.match(currentHand);
        probabilities.addWeight(hand, 1);

        // Store a random sample for the poker hand if we haven't
        // done so yet. This works because the combinations are
        // generated from a shuffled deck so the first match will
        // be a truly random sample.
        final List<Card> sample = samples.get(hand);
        if (sample == null) {
            samples.put(hand, new ArrayList<>(dealtCards));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the probabilities for each poker hand.
     */
    WeightedSet<PokerHand> getProbabilities() {
        return probabilities;
    }

    /**
     * Get a random card sample that creates the given poker hand
     * when combined with that cards held by the player.
     */
    List<Card> getRandomSample(PokerHand hand) {
        return samples.get(hand);
    }
}
```

The card dealer combines the previous components:

```
package fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.luckbased;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.Card;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.Dealer;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.DeckSupplier;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.PokerHand;
import fi.iki.asb.videopoker.game.handmatcher.HandMatcher;
import fi.iki.asb.wheel.adt.impl.WeightedSet;
import fi.iki.asb.wheel.algorithm.Combinator;
import fi.iki.asb.wheel.algorithm.Shuffle;
import fi.iki.asb.wheel.algorithm.impl.FisherYatesShuffle;

public class ProbabilityBasedDealer implements Dealer {

    private final Random random = new Random();

    private final Shuffle shuffle = new FisherYatesShuffle(random);

    private final HandMatcher handMatcher;

    private final List<Card> deck;
    
    private final Consumer<WeightedSet<PokerHand>> probabilityAdjuster;

    /**
     * Cards that are held by the player.
     */
    private final List<Card> heldCards;

    /**
     * Cards that have been discarded by the player.
     */
    private final List<Card> discardedCards;

    public ProbabilityBasedDealer(
            final DeckSupplier deckSupplier,
            final HandMatcher handMatcher,
            final Consumer<WeightedSet<PokerHand>> probabilityAdjuster) {
        this.deck = deckSupplier.getCards();
        this.handMatcher = handMatcher;
        this.probabilityAdjuster = probabilityAdjuster;

        heldCards = new ArrayList<>(5);
        discardedCards = new ArrayList<>(5);
    }

    @Override
    public void shuffleDeck() {
        deck.addAll(discardedCards);
        discardedCards.clear();
        heldCards.clear();
        shuffle.shuffle(deck);
    }

    @Override
    public void discard(Collection<Card> cards) {
        discardedCards.addAll(cards);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Card> dealCards(int cardCount) {
        // Find out all possible outcomes for stocking up the player's hand.
        final PokerHandProbabilityCounter combinationConsumer =
                new PokerHandProbabilityCounter(
                        handMatcher, heldCards);
        final Combinator<Card> combinator = new Combinator<>(
                deck, cardCount);
        combinator.findCombinations(combinationConsumer);

        // Adjust the probabilities of each possible poker hand.
        final WeightedSet<PokerHand> probabilities = combinationConsumer
                .getProbabilities();
        probabilityAdjuster.accept(probabilities);

        // Get a random poker hand and return the random sample.
        final PokerHand pokerHand = probabilities.get(random.nextDouble());
        final List<Card> dealtCards = combinationConsumer.getRandomSample(pokerHand);

        heldCards.addAll(dealtCards);
        deck.removeAll(dealtCards);
        return dealtCards;
    }
}
```